# Fading Images with links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code for the header

```
<div id="header"> 
<IMG SRC="http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/shugar/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/header-principal.png"> 
</div>
```

And this code for the main menu

```
<div id="menu"> 
<a href="url">Link One</a>,
<a href="url">Link Two</a>,
<a href="url">Link Three</a>
</div>
```

I want the header image to fade into another image through the main menu links. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Ya its possible if you are marking a SPA(single page application) or else you have to handle it in your page load code while you are loading the page up by recognizing the page and accordingly loading the image in the header bar...

Comment: In addition to the previous comment - do you want it to occur on hover?

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/e395xg4L/ that should get you going in the right direction

Comment: @Parody I tried it and It didn't work, look [link](http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/shugar)

Comment: @LosSimpsonLatinoamerica you havnt included a jquery libary, `<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>` add that

Answer (score 1):

First of all most W3C folks will get mad at you for this line `<div id="header">`

Anything syntactically named with an id the same as a generic HTML object tag needs to just be that tag. Anything good enough to give an id of `id='header'` should probably just be a `<header>` tag.

Secondly, I am unsure what the question is asking fully so let's go with something not yet said. @Parody showed a fiddled way of having the images change on click. The part of your question that said `I want the header image to fade into another image through the main menu links. Is this possible?` is difficult to understand so I am going to assume that you want some kind of event to trigger the changing of the images? There are many ways to do this but the best of which (especially for beginning programmers) is to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) version 3.0+ since it comes with HTML driven stuff that usually requires JavaScript/JQuery to accomplish.

If you don't want to use Bootstrap then that's fine here is an example of how to use a `hover` event to trigger the change using JQuery...

**HTML**

```
<div id="header"> 
    <img src="http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/shugar/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/header-principal.png" /> 
</div>

<div id="menu"> 
    <a href="url" class="navLink" data-image="http://www.newsucanuse.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/sexy-woman.jpg">Link One</a>
    <a href="url" class="navLink" data-image="http://www.datingdynamics.com/dating-advice-for-guys/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/woman-sexy-hd-celebrity-81758.jpg">Link Two</a>
    <a href="url" class="navLink" data-image="http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/12700000/Xtina-looking-hot-christina-aguilera-12723427-490-628.jpg">Link Three</a>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY**

```
$(".navLink").each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $("#header img").css({"background-image":"url($(this).attr('data-image'))"});
    });
});
```